# Modal not getting opened on clicking the image of gallery component

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to open a model when I click on the image component in the gallery. Here I'm not getting the "flagImage" variable updated in onPress method of TouchableOpacity or the modal component is not getting the updated value of "flagImage" when onPress of TouchableOpacity changes its value. I need help here. The modal doesn't open at all whenever I touch the image component. It just does nothing :( Below is the code for gallery.component.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Modal, Text } from 'react-native';
import styles from './cameraStyles';

export default ({captures=[], flagImage=true}) => (
  <ScrollView
    horizontal={true}
    style={[styles.bottomToolbar, styles.galleryContainer]}
  >
      {captures.map(({ uri }) => (
        <View style={styles.galleryImageContainer} key={uri}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={()=> {
                  flagImage = !flagImage;
                  console.log('Touch: "'+flagImage+'"');
              }}
            >
                <Image source={{ uri }} style={styles.galleryImage}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Modal visible={flagImage} onPress={() => {console.log('Modal: "'+flagImage+'"');flagImage = !flagImage;}} onRequestClose={() => flagImage = ! flagImage}>
                <View>
                    <Image source={{ uri }} style={styles.galleryImageLarge}/>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </View>
      ))}
  </ScrollView>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of useState hook to convert the props into a state where you can update them.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Modal, Text } from 'react-native';
import styles from './cameraStyles';

export default ({captures=[], lflagImage=false}) => {
    const [flagImage, setflagImage] = React.useState(lflagImage);
    return (
    
        <ScrollView 
            horizontal={true}
            style={[styles.bottomToolbar, styles.galleryContainer]} 
        >
            {captures.map(({ uri }) => (
                <View style={flagImage?styles.galleryImageContainer:styles.galleryImageContainerView} key={uri}>
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                        onPress={()=> {
                            setflagImage(prevData => !prevData)
                            console.log('Touch: "'+flagImage+'"');          
                        }}
                    >
                        <Image source={{ uri }} style={flagImage?styles.galleryImage:styles.galleryImageLarge}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Modal visible={flagImage} onRequestClose={() => setflagImage(prevData => !prevData)}>
                        <View>
                                <Image source={{ uri }} style={styles.galleryImageLarge}/>
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
                </View>
            ))}
        </ScrollView>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Getting the below error:

SyntaxError: E:\Mobile App Development\Advanced Experimentation\TrendingCam\src\gallery.component.js: Unexpected token (6:4)

  4 |
  5 | export default ({captures=[], flagImage=false}) => (
> 6 |     const [flagImage, setflagImage] = React.useState(flagImage);
    |     ^
  7 |     <ScrollView
  8 |         horizontal={true}
  9 |         style={[styles.bottomToolbar, styles.galleryContainer]}

Comment: take a look at the props I changed the name of the props.

Comment: Used same code as posted by you above still getting the same error:

SyntaxError: E:\Mobile App Development\Advanced Experimentation\TrendingCam\src\gallery.component.js: Unexpected token (6:4)

  4 |
  5 | export default ({captures=[], lflagImage=false}) => (
> 6 |     const [flagImage, setflagImage] = React.useState(lflagImage);
    |     ^
  7 |     <ScrollView
  8 |         horizontal={true}
  9 |         style={[styles.bottomToolbar, styles.galleryContainer]}

Comment: I updated the code before the useState hook is inside the return statement. This should not happen useState hook must be outside of the return statement.

Comment: Yeah that worked. I was missing this part, I was skipping the return statement and hence I was not able to use state in this component. Thanks a lot for your answer.